# proving that union of relations is transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I need some help with proving the following:

Let A be a set where $\left|A\right|=n$

Need to prove that the following is a transitive relation  $\bigcup_{i\in\left\{0,\ldots,n-1\right\}} R^{\left(i\right)}$

(where $R^{\left(i\right)}=R\circ R\circ\ldots\circ R$ (the relation composition i times))

Well the basis was pretty easy - I got the identity relation, but I'm stuck on the induction step. I would appriciate any help!

Comment: What was $R^{(i)}$ again?

Comment: $R^{\left(i\right)}=R\circ R\circ\ldots\circ R$ (the relation composition i times)
Sorry about it, I will edit my post!

Comment: And then $R$?  Is it just any relation?  Or a specific relation that was defined in a part of your post that you left out?

Comment: R is any relation on set A , nothing specific

Comment: What induction?

Comment: maybe it is not induction, but I tried to prove it with induction on $n$

Comment: What is your induction statement?

Comment: well the inducton basis is when n=1 , and then $\bigcup_{i\in\left\{0\right\}} R^{\left(i\right)}=\ \ \ R^{\left(0\right)}=\ \ \ Id_A$.
then the step whould be "lets say the statment is correct for $n$" and try proving it for $n+1$

Comment: Actually, $R^{(0)}$ is the empty relation, not the identity, isn't it? In which case, I would expect it to fail for $n=2$...

Comment: well it was told us to assume that $R^{\left(0\right)}$ is the identity...

Comment: Oh, fair enough; it could be defined as the neutral element of composition to allow for arbitrary associativity...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do induction. The inductive step would be annoying: you would want to take a subset $B$ of $A$ with $k$ elements, restrict the relation, deduce the appropriate union (which is a subset of the union you want) is transitive, and then leverage that into showing the union you *do* have is transitive, which would likely involve cases depending on whether the "extra" element shows up or not.

Let $T=\cup_{k=0}^{n-1}R^{(k)}$. Let $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ be elements of $T$. You want to prove that $(a,c)\in T$.

There exist $i$ and $j$ such that $(a,b)\in R^{(i)}$ and $(b,c)\in R^{(j)}$. If $i=0$ then $a=b$, so you have $(a,c)=(b,c)\in T$. If $j=0$, then $b=c$, so $(a,c)=(a,b)\in T$. Thus, we may assume that $i\gt 0$ and $j\gt 0$.

Thus, there exist $x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_i$, $y_0,y_1,\ldots,y_j$ in $A$ such that
$$ a=x_0,\ x_i=b,\ (x_r,x_{r+1})\in R\\
b=y_0,\ y_{j}=c,\ (y_s,y_{s+1})\in R.$$

If you have two $x$s that are the same, we can shorten the chain that yields $(a,b)$, so we may assume that $x_0,\ldots,x_i$ are pairwise distinct. Likewise, if $y_0,\ldots,y_j$ are not pairwise distinct, we can shorten the chain, and so we may assume that they *are* pairwise distinct.

If $i+j\lt n$, then we can simply take the sequence
$$(x_0,x_1),\ldots,(x_{i-1},x_i),(y_0,y_1),\ldots,(y_{j-1},y_j)$$
of elements of $R$, and since $x_i=b=y_0$, their composition lies in $R^{(i+j)}$, which is a subset of $T$, and equals $(x_0,y_j) = (a,c)$. Thus, $(a,c)\in T$.

If $i+j\geq n$, then you want to find some way to shorten this sequence of pairs so as to get a sequence with no more than $n-1$ steps.

Now, notice that we *haven't* used the fact that $|A|=n$. So perhaps that will come in useful here?

Comment: Hi, this is amazing, thanks a lot! I will try to continue it :)